# How to set position for checkboxes/radiobuttons in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-form2

I tried it so:

```
<?php
echo $this->formRow($form->get('weekday'), Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow::LABEL_PREPEND);
?>
```

But the labels are still staying behind the checkboxes.

[image]

How should I set the label position correctly?

Comment: Can you try setting `option { label_position = 'append' }` on your `weekday`-element? :) This may solve it already, but I'm not too sure, if not i have a longer solution ready :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is weekday a multi-checkbox? If so, use the render method **formMultiCheckbox** instead of **formRow** and the label will be positioned where you want.

I've been debugging the process and that's an strange behaviour. When the class **Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormRow** is invoked, the label's position is initialized as you expect (**LABEL_PREPEND**).

Later, the class **Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox** is called but it doesn't inherit the position from **FormRow**, and uses its default value, which is the one you don't want, **LABEL_APPEND**.

Check the **__invoke** method on both classes and you'll see.

Comment: It needs to be pointed out, that the `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` needs to be rendered manually, since the `FormMultiCheckbox` only rendered the checkboxes. This is why i asked for the other try above with setting the label_position as an option to the element, which should solve the issue ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response! It works now! This behaviour is not so strange. There are two types of label in a radio / multicheckbox: the label of the whole set and the label of each element: `<label>type_1<label>type_2<input /></label><label>type_2<input /></label></label>` (in ZF the `type_2` doesn't get a `label` tagby default). I think it's good, that the label position of `type_1` (the whole checkbox set) is not inherited from each checkbox (`type_2`). The other question is: how to set both? Since one cannot nest `formRow(...)` and `formMultiCheckbox(...)` in each other...

Comment: @automatix did you try setting the `label_position` option?

Comment: What I wrote in my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938320/how-to-set-position-for-checkboxes-radiobuttons-in-zend-framework-2#comment22718124_15942507) yesterday is wrong. Anyway I cannot reproduce this behaviour now. `$this->formMultiCheckbox($form->get('weekday'), FormMultiCheckbox::LABEL_PREPEND)` actually sets the label text before the checkbox.